# В чём разница между MTOM и XOP?

Tags: xml, wsdl

У меня возникла проблема с пониманием терминов. Как я их понимаю:

**XOP** - это механизм для работы с бинарными данными в XML. Т.е. бинарные данные упаковываются отдельно, а в самом XML указывается только ссылка на бинарные данные.

**MTOM** - это технология, которая использует XOP.

Я не понимаю, в чём разница. У меня в связи с этим возникают вопросы:

1. Если XOP уже упаковывает бинарные файлы в MIME-сообщения, то зачем нужна дополнительная абстракция в виде MTOM?
2. Возможно ли использовать XOP без MTOM?

Comment: XOP - метод для ссылок на бинарные данные. MTOM - набор соглашений как использовать такие ссылки согласованным образом. Теоретически MTOM может опираться на механизм отличный от XOP. Результат оверинжиниринга - оба механизма разрабатывались как отдельные, а используются почти всегда вместе.